# Flex font rendering differences from 4.1 to 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm currently upgrading an app from Flex 4.1 to 4.5

We've noticed that the Arial font is rendered differently between the two versions when used at small sizes.

Here's a simple app example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        @font-face { 
            src: url("/assets/fonts/ARIAL.ttf"); 
            fontFamily: arial; 
            embedAsCFF: true; 
        }
        @font-face { 
            src: url("/assets/fonts/ARIALBD.ttf"); 
            fontFamily: arial; 
            embedAsCFF: true; 
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        global
        {
            font-family: arial;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <s:Label text="Hello world" fontWeight="bold" x="20" y="20"  />
</s:Application>
```

When run against the 2 different sdks, here's an image of the font rendering we get:

[image: Example of font issues]

Note that in 4.5 the font looks slightly squashed.

What's the cause of this, and how do we resolve it?

Comment: I see this as well. Notice that the i-character (e.g. "i"), looks like an "l" because the dot disappears. One way to resolve is to increase the font size a bit. As an aside, I'm also noticing that MX components' fonts (in my case based on the exact same font file used by Spark components, but with a style configured correctly for MX) display thinner than they should. In particular, the period (e.g. ".") almost disappears (it's only 1 pixel).

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that it's related to [the changes that were made](http://devgirl.org/2011/04/11/flash-builder-4-5-mobile-highlights/) to support fonts on handheld devices. To fix it you may have to play around with your style sheet settings a bit.

> **CSS Media Queries**
>   You can now use @media rules in your style sheets to
>   filter CSS rules based on the device’s
>   DPI classification. There are two
>   properties you can filter on
>   currently, os-platform and
>   application-dpi. Here’s an example of
>   filtering on them to set a button font
>   for instance (from Adobe’s prerelease
>   docs):

```
@media (os-platform: "Android") and (application-dpi: 240) {
s|Button {
     fontSize: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To temporally fix this just specify SWF version 10 on the flex-config.xml

```
look for <swf-version>11</swf-version> and make that a 10

(the "target-player" tag remains as 10.2.0)
```

This config will allow you to use the 10.2 new API but I guess it will miss the Hardware Optimizations (maybe no StageVideo... warning: I am not sure and haven't tested yet. The only thing I did was to check it the 10.2 specific methods was there, like "requestSoftKeyboard")

I guess this issue has something to do with the new "Sub-pixel Text Rendering" Adobe promoted on 10.2 release **OR** maybe the new player is just rendering the text differently.

By the way, this issue is really ugly, small fonts gets blurry and medium size fonts gets noticeably squashed!

Any **real** fix, that allow us to target SWF 11, please let us know.